# iptables DROP vs REJECT on http

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I am trying to understand iptables and begin my hand-on today. I was trying to set rules for my http server. I have had accept rules initially, and I was able to successfully perform a wget. Later, I changed the rules to DROP and REJECT to notice the working.

Here's what I noticed.

My system is able to connect to port 80 in both the cases and in both the cases but no do a wget, I get a message re-trying. Isn't DROP supposed avoid giving any message? But they both exactly do the same things. I have also made sure that either of the rules exist not to have any conflict. I feel some basic of mine is missing. Also upon having either DROP or REJECT, how is it that it is able to connect to the sever on port 80 but of course not receive a reply?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target prot opt source destination 
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:http 
target prot opt source destination 
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:http reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Please show the iptables rules you created.

Comment: @MichaelHampton:  Here they are.

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) <br>
target     prot opt source               destination  <br/>  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh <br/>
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http <br/>
target     prot opt source               destination   <br/>      
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh <br/>
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http reject-with icmp-port-unreachable<br/>

Comment: Please edit the question and add the rules there in a code block. It is hard to read from a comment.